# Spring Boot - Dynamically Restrict IP address

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this Bean:

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean remoteAddressFilter() {

        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        RemoteAddrFilter filter = new RemoteAddrFilter();
        filter.setAllow("(.*?)");
        filter.setDeny("192\\.168\\.0\\.2");
        filter.setDenyStatus(404);

        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");

        return filterRegistrationBean;
```

Is there a way to dynamically change this filter after the application has started? I have already implemented a Login Attempt Listener that identifies when an IP address issued some amount of failed Authentication Attempts. On Spring Boot tutorials suggests, to use a Runtime Exception when an IP is blocked, but I don`t like that option.

Comment: Create a listener, which has a dependency to the filter and modify accordingly. Or write a method in Spring Security which handles this instead of the `RemoteAddrFilter` and store the addresses/ranges in the database.

Comment: Can you provide an example, please... I can block it only after a login request has been made. But I don't want to do that. I want to be blocked in "firewall" level

Comment: In practical terms, it is typically much cleaner to use a firewall or similar rule to do this.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Yes that is what I want but how an already started application modifies an existing firewall rule?